# How to create a database for HDF5 files

Tags: python, database, api, hdf5

I am trying to create a database for a bunch of hdf5 files that are on my computer like more than a few hundreds. This database will be used by many people and then i need to create a API to be used to access the database.
So any idea how i can create a database that can contain the HDF5 files in a single place ??
I need to use python to create a database.

Comment: Generally speaking, it is not a very good idea to store (big) files in a relational database. You can use a binary repository manager instead. See: https://binary-repositories-comparison.github.io/

Comment: The database need not be a relational database it can be any....But i just need a way to store hdf files in a database. If any i would love to know

Comment: Have you considered a HDF5 file with external symbolic links to the other files? Seems like a perfect application.